# $F_*(X\cdot Y)=F_*X\cdot F_*Y$ and $[F_*X,F_*Y]=F_*[X,Y]$

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to know if 
$$F_*(X\cdot Y)=F_*X\cdot F_*Y\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
where $F:M\rightarrow N$ is smooth and $X,Y\in \mathcal{X}(M)$. The operation $\cdot$ (which I will omit from now on) is the composition of vector fields as derivations: $X\cdot Y(f):=X(Y(f))$, where $f\in C^\infty(M)$.

I tried the following:

Let $g\in C^\infty(N)$. Then:

$$
F_*(XY)(g) = XY(g\circ F)= X\Big( Y(g\circ F) \Big)
$$

On the other hand

$$
(F_*X\  F_*Y )(g) = F_*X (F_*Y (g)) = F_*X\Big( Y(g\circ F) \Big) = X\Big( Y(g\circ F) \circ F \Big)
$$

So it seems that the proposition is false after all. However, it seems that

$$
(X\  F_*Y )(g) = X (F_*Y (g)) = X\Big( Y(g\circ F) \Big) = F_*(XY)(g)
$$
So that $$X\  F_*Y=F_*(XY)$$

I wonder if this is true.

---

*Context:*

I was hoping (1) to be true because I was originally trying to prove the following:

> Let $F:G\rightarrow H$ be a Lie group homomorphism. Then, $F_*$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism.

So I want to show that $$[F_*X,F_*Y]=F_*[X,Y]$$ and this is a 3-step proof if $(1)$ holds.

Comment: I was wondering what is your $X\cdot Y$. It can't be a vector field. So what is the action $F_*$ acting on it....

Comment: @JohnMa It is not defined, then...

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that an arbitrary smooth map does not define a pushforward operation on vector fields. The formula you're trying to use, $(F_*X)(g) = X(g\circ F)$, does not define a vector field on $N$, because $X(g\circ F)$ is a function on $M$, not on $N$. In order to push forward arbitrary vector fields, $F$ has to be a diffeomorphism. If $F$ is a Lie group homomorphism, there is a special definition of $F_*X$ if $X$ is a _left-invariant_ vector field; but you can't apply $F_*$ to arbitrary vector fields, let alone to a differential operator like $XY$.

Comment: @JackLee I see... I still don't know how to prove the result under "context", though. It is supposed to be easy, I believe, but I do not see how. At least without assuming $F$ to be invertible.

Comment: Do you know about $F$-related vector fields, and how they behave under Lie bracket?

Comment: @JackLee I do know about $F$-related fields, but I do not know how they behave under Lie bracket.

Comment: @JackLee I thought that this was precisely the result that tells us how they behave under Lie bracket.

Comment: The thing you're trying to prove is a very special case of a general result about Lie brackets of $F$-related vector fields. You can find the general result, for example, in Proposition 8.30 of my _Intro to Smooth Manifolds_ (2nd ed.).

Comment: @JackLee I only have the first edition... Could you please tell me the corresponding proposition?

Comment: It's Prop. 4.16.